# How long are Cloudwatch Insights Query results retained?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

When you use the AWS API to [run a query against Cloudwatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_StartQuery.html), you get back a `queryId`.

```
{
   "queryId": "string"
}
```

You can then [call GetQueryResults using that query ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueryResults.html) and retrieve results from the query.

```
{
   "results": [ 
      [ 
         { 
            "field": "string",
            "value": "string"
         }
      ]
   ],
   "statistics": { 
      "bytesScanned": number,
      "recordsMatched": number,
      "recordsScanned": number
   },
   "status": "string"
}
```

My question is **how long are these query results retained?** Can I run a query, and come back a month later to get the results? A year later?

I can't seem to find any documentation from Amazon that explains the retention policy. In the absence of an official source, I'll accept answers based on anecdotal experience using this API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the CloudWatch Logs quotas page:

> Results from a query are retrievable for 7 days. This availability time can't be changed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't even use Cloudwatch any more, but here's hoping others will get some value.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, the CW Logs retention is "forever" - see [the official documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html)

> By default, logs are kept indefinitely and never expire. You can adjust the retention policy for each log group, keeping the indefinite retention, or choosing a retention periods between 10 years and one day.

You do get charged when you retrieved such data.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's not clear from the question: I was asking about the query results specifically, not the raw logs that they're derived from. Maybe they also last forever?

Comment: ah, sorry. I do not expect the query and its queryid to be persisted indefinitely, but there are no clearly written retention this granular.
Is there a reason why you wouldn't resubmit the query and get a new id?

Comment: I have too many matching results to get back from a single query, so I need to run multiple queries over narrower time intervals, and then collect all the results together after the queries complete. I'm wondering how long I can wait to run the collect task, or if I risk older queries expiring?

Comment: blmc, Did you ever find out an answer to this or notice your queries expiring? I've been creating a bunch of queries as part of development - and my describe_queries function is returning a lot of cruft.

Comment: Well this sounds promising in the description for Describe Queries: "Returns a list of CloudWatch Logs Insights queries that are scheduled, executing, or have been executed recently in this account."

So it sounds like they just fall off after a while.